# NodeJS monorepo with non-npm project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, monorepo, pnpm

Basically I'd like to know how to share code between nodejs projects. There is a module need to be used by multiple projects, lets call it shared module, the shared module has its own package.json and dependencies. at development I can use pnpm or typescript path alias to make it work, but I do not want to publish the shared module to the npm registry, so the question is how do I make it avaliable for these projects that use it as dependency which runs on server or published to users?

the code structure:

```
/packages
  /shared
    package.json
  /api-server // runs on server
    package.json
  /cool-cli  // published to NPM
    package.json
```

Currently I was use `npm install ../shared` to make it avaliable for api-server, but this makes me write a kind of complexity publish script and I don't know if its a workable way for NPM packages too, I may need to publish the cool-cli like this:

```
/dist
/shared
package.json
{
  ...
 dependencies: {
   "shared": "./shared"
 }
}
```

I also have another idea is to bundle the shared module to other projects' source code without a separate package.json, but this wont work for dependencies that can not bundle into js.

Comment: Take a look at npm workspaces

Comment: @Evert , I have used pnpm workspace on my local development, bit I think we couldn't publish a npm package with pnpm workspace protocol right? this not gonna work for the npm user

Comment: No experience with `pnpm`, but `npm` workspaces does seem specifically for solving your use-case: multiple local packages that aren't published anywhere but just part of your monorepo. This is way superious to typescript aliases which have all kinds of issues, and `npm install ../package` which makes a copy every time.